# WSO2 CEP + Handle null values

Tags: wso2, complex-event-processing, siddhi, wso2-cep

Currently WSO2 CEP is triggered using some Http requests. But some times triggered request has null values. At that time how to handle those null values using CEP.

Comment: Is it about sending events to CEP http receivers where some attributes have null values?

Comment: Yes @TharikKanaka, It has null values.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There two ways of fixing this

1. Using default values in Event Receiver input event mapping https://docs.wso2.com/display/CEP410/Input+Mapping+Types
2. Using Siddhi by checking `is null` operator with in the query https://docs.wso2.com/display/CEP410/SiddhiQL+Guide+3.0#SiddhiQLGuide3.0-QueryProjection